# How can I permanently prevent outlook from classifiying certain messages as clutter

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

We've recently been moved to Office 365, and I primarily access my email using the outlook client.

I receive a lot of messages generated by monitoring software running on servers. In most cases I don't need to open these messages to see what action I need to take, as the subject line tells me everything I need to know.

However, if I delete messages without opening them, Outlook seems to classify them as clutter, so from then on they end up in my clutter folder. Not good for an email that might need urgent attention!

I've found various resources saying that I can tell outlook to reclassify them by dragging them back to the inbox. However that does not seem to stick: if I continue deleting these messages without opening them, after a few days they start going back to clutter.

The only reference I could find to black listing these emails from clutter was [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn896639(v=exchg.150).aspx), but it describes creating transport rules in the Outlook server, not something I can do.

Is there any way to permanently instruct Outlook not to place messages in clutter, short of turning the function off altogether?

Comment: If the email needs urgent attention, why are you deleting it, without even reading it?

Comment: @Ramhound Because the subject line (visible from the message list) tells me all I need to know. It would be something like `Notice #28070: HTTPS down on as11.abc.xyz.com (172.16.85.3) on node as11.abc.xyz.com.`. The email body is empty.